# PHP remove tab(\t) tacks on random numbers

Tags: php

I appear to be having a problem with string replace

```
$vals= "1/5/2012    $4,510.64 
";  //simulating web entry that would be copied and pasted from excel.
$vals = str_replace(array("\t"), " ", $vals);
echo $vals;
```

1/5/2012 $4,510.64 13257216001415138792

same for trim

```
$vals= "1/5/2012    $4,510.64 
";
$vals=trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', ' ', $vals));
echo $vals;
```

1/5/2012 $4,510.641325721600

But if I tell it not to replace tabs with spaces, but instead delete them, THEN it doesnt add on any junk.

```
$vals= "1/5/2012    $4,510.64 
";
$vals=trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $vals));
echo $vals;
```

1/5/2012$4,510.64

A little help?  I would love for tabs to get replaced with spaces without random numbers being tacked on at the end.  Thanks

Comment: Just a goofy guess, but maybe there's some extra data on the end of the line of pasted text? Possibly outside of the textbox's view? Copying an entire row from excel can get you some pretty odd results!

Comment: Ive been looking into that... but if that was the problem, why does it go away when I trim(preg_replace to nothing instead of a single space?

Comment: That's just it, I don't know. Your code looks fine to me and that's why I questioned the input data.